# Not searching when using Autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete

I followed this tutorial: http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association

*But It did not work.*

What I did was the following:

I installed the plugin using

```
rails plugin install git://github.com/rails/auto_complete.git
```

In my message.rb I declare user_name

```
 def user_name
    user.username if user
  end

  def user_name= (username)
    self.user = User.find_or_create_by_username(username) unless username.blank?
  end
```

In my application.html.haml i added

```
= javascript_include_tag :defaults
```

In my profile/users/index.js.erb

```
<%= auto_complete_result @users, :username %>
```

I tried running `http://localhost:8080/profile/users.js`

And it outputs the intended list of users.

In my users_controller.rb

```
    auto_complete_for :message, :user_name
  def index
    @users = User.find(:all, :conditions => ['username LIKE ?', "%#{params[:search]}%"])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.js # index.js.erb
    end
  end
```

When i rake routes i get the proper output needed for views

```
 profile_users GET    /profile/users(.:format)                                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"profile/users"}
```

Finally in my profile/messages/compose.html.haml

```
= form_for :message, :url => send_message_profile_messages_path do |message|
  %label{:for => "friend"} To:
  %br
  = text_field_with_auto_complete :message,:user_name, {:size => 15} , {:url =>profile_users_path(:format => :js), :method => :get, :param_name => 'search' }
  %br
  %label{:for => "message"} Body:
  %br
  = message.text_area :message
  %br
  = message.file_field :attachment
  %br
  = submit_tag "Send", :confirm => "Are you sure?"
```

What Have I done wrong?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using, and are you using the revised tutorial or the original one?

If it's the original, unless you're using a very dated version or Rails, I'd assume that's the problem.

I recommend checking out the jQuery UI autocomplete. It's very easy to implement, degrades gracefully, and doesn't require any ruby code at all.

Comment: Do you know a good tutorial about jQuery UI autocomplete? Thanks cc: @jbarket

Comment: I would take a look at the example apps people have on github. If you search for rails jqueryui autocomplete, you'll find a handful. It is super easy though. I tend to use the combobox approach a lot, and basically I just drop a normal collection_select out in Rails, then call my autocompleter on it